# Custom Class Inside a WCF Service Object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

A bit rusty here with regards to WCF Services.

I have a custom class named cSecurity.cs which does some custom functions.

I want to use this custom class inside my Service:

This is the App.svc.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;  

namespace AppServices
    {
        public class App : IApp
        {
            public cSecurity _csec;

            public string GetItems(int agentID, string agentName)
            {
                // Need to use some functions from the cSecurity class here???
                return _csec.getItems();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the cSecurity.cs class:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Net;

    namespace AppServices
    {
        public class cSecurity
        {
          // Some functions defined here....
          public string getItems(){
            return string.Empty;
          }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error on the line:

```
public cSecurity _csec;
```

"The type or namespace name 'cSecurity' could not be found."

This seems pretty trivial but I seem to be lost here.

Appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the assembly that contains App has a reference to the assembly that contains cSecurity.  Also make sure you have a using statement in  your file that contains App to the namespace of cSecurity.

Comment: cSecurity.cs is just a custom class that is also along the directory where the Service resides. Not completely getting your suggestion here.

Comment: So your file that contains the definition of cSecurity looks something like this? `namespace AppServices { public class cSecurity { ... } }`

Comment: Yes. I added some more code snippets..

Comment: Sorry to give you this type of an answer, but it works for me.  Just copy-pasted your code and it compiles (with trivial modification).

Comment: That's what confuses me, as I think the cSecurity class should be detected, but for some reason, it is being marked and displays the error when compiling. Getting lost and confused here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41931/discussion-between-angelo-and-tylerohlsen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the solution for this was for me to close and restart VS. Not sure what caused the class for it to be not referenced by VS.